# MacOS zsh prompt does not show Purple?

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm trying to make my `git branch` purple. Here's what I have:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
    # git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2> /dev/null
}

setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PS1='%{%F{green}%}%n@%m:%{%F{yellow}%}%1~%{%F{red}%}$(parse_git_branch)%{%F{none}%}$ '
```

So my `username@machine:` is green and `foldername` is yellow as expected. However, if I change the colour `red` to `purple` or anything else but `white` or `cyan`, my prompt doesn't show the correct colour.

FYI: Here's what I have in `bash`:

```sh
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[0;33m\]\W\[\033[0;35m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

I've tried:

- `for i in {1..256}; do print -P "%F{$i}Color : $i"; done;` and my terminal shows all ranges of colours so I replaced `red` with some ANSI code but the branch turns `cyan`.
- `\e[0;31m$ \e[0m` with ANSI escape char but it still doesn't work.
- `$F{}`, `$fg{}`, etc.
- And of course quit the terminal, source the `~/.zshrc` file, restart computer.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the output of `parse_git_branch`? Does it maybe contain code to set Cyan explicitly? And what is the purpose of `%}`? I don't use it in my prompt configuration.

Comment: You can see the output of parse_git_branch() function in the code. It only shows the git branch. No, it doesn't set colour as I've done it in `bash`.

Comment: `purple` isn't a known color; use `magenta` instead.

Comment: The only predefined color names are black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, and white. For other colors, you need to specify a color number (corresponding to your terminal's palette) or an RGB triplet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `%F{...}`, you can use one of the following:

1. An integer corresponding to an entry in your terminal's palette (the range depends on the size of that palette). That's what you saw with your `for` loop (though you can use `i=0` as well; see the next point). E.g. `%F{red}`
2. One of the predefined names `black`, `red`, `green`, `yellow`, `blue`, `magenta`, `cyan`, or `white` (corresponding to palette entries 0 through 7, respectively). E.g. `%F{1}` (Note that some terminals may support additional names.)
3. An RGB value, starting with a `#` and followed by 3 or 6 hexadecimal digits. E.g. `%F{#f00}` or %F{#ff0000}`

   Assuming your terminal allows it, this provides you with more control over the color displayed, as both `%F{red}` and `%F{1}` simply tell the terminal to display color #1 (which the terminal emulator may allow to be set to any color the user likes). `%F{#ff0000}`, on the other hand, will *always* display the brightest shade of red available.