# oh-my-zsh with git does not update the git banner in the prompt to green even when git status is up to date

Tags: git, oh-my-zsh

I had a local folder that got pushed to git mistakenly at one point. I fixed it(git-ignored it, deleted it from remote, git pulled, etc.) to get them back in sync.

However, oh-my-zsh (with `powerlevel10k` theme) will not change the prompt's git banner back to green.

I have tried restarting `iterm`, reloading `zshrc`, removing git plugin and adding it back to `zshrc`, but none of this works.

Screenshot shows git status is clean, but the prompt still shows git status as yellow instead of green.

[image: git banner looks yellow though status is up to date]

Comment: [Related, but don't know if it is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63364693/1256452); [also related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61449730/1256452)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first to clone again your repository in a separate, to check if the issue persists (if the zsh prompt, in that new folder, is still incorrect).

From [issue 559](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/559), you can see what produces the yellow segement:

```sh
  if $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1); then
    repo_path=$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)
    dirty=$(parse_git_dirty)
    ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || ref="➦ $(git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null)"
    if [[ -n $dirty ]]; then
      prompt_segment yellow black
    else
      prompt_segment green $CURRENT_FG
    fi
```

(With [`parse_git_dirty` here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/git.zsh#L35-L61))